# How to show $T: C^n\rightarrow C^n$ defined by $T(x)=\bar{x}$ is not a linear tranformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

We write $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then $T(x)=(\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2,\ldots,\bar{x}_n)$

$T(ax)=(\overline{ax}_1, \overline{ax}_2,\ldots,\overline{ax}_n)=$ Here I am not sure what to write as I don't know what $\overline{ax}_n$ equals.

And I have the same question for $T(x+y)$: what does $\overline{x_n+y_n}$ equal

Comment: $T(ax)$ would be $(\bar{a}\cdot\bar{x_1},\ldots,\bar{a}\cdot\bar{x_n})=\bar{a}\cdot\bar{x}\neq a\cdot\bar{x}=a\cdot T(x)$.

Comment: But why is $\bar{a}\ne a$?

Comment: @1412 what is $\bar i$?

Comment: I know your meaning but isn't complex conjugate only applying to imaginary part? I think $a$ is the real part?

Comment: @1412 why should $a$ only be real? Is $T$ supposed to be $\mathbb C$ linear or $\mathbb R$ linear? In the first case no, the second case yes.

Comment: $a$ represents a scalar in the field associated with the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$.  In this case the field is $\mathbb{C}$, so $a$ isn't necessarily real.